# Did the Red Cross cure 154 Malaria cases with MMS within 48 hours?

Tags: medical-science, video, chlorine, malaria

The following YouTube video:

- [Proof the Red Cross Cured 154 Malaria Cases with MMS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrwZN1cPfX8)

> finally proves that the Red Cross did a field test showing malaria was cured using MMS (sodium chlorite + activating acid producing chlorine dioxide) with a 100% success rate in 154 cases within 24-48 hours. This formerly hidden video was kept from the public for over 5 months until recently discovered.

Few claims:

- > 6:07 -- Klaas Proesmans: "It has been said and written that the use of sodium chlorite cleans the body within one hour to four hours of the malaria parasite. That was too good to be true not to go further and do an investigation..."
- > 10:43 -- Klaas Proesmans: "In total we identified 154 malaria positive patients, together with the local health {authorities} or the doctors. All of them were treated. All of them were, between 24 hours and 48 hours, malaria negative... without any side effects!"

Additional explanation: MMS (or [MMS1](http://mmswiki.is/index.php/Mixing_a_Basic_Dose_of_MMS1)) is a solution coined by [Jim Humble](http://mmswiki.is/index.php/Archbishop_Jim_Humble) which is produced by mixing few drops of a 22.4% solution of sodium chlorite in purified water with an acid activator (e.g.  10-40% citric acid), which produces active chlorine dioxide, then added in a glass of water so it can be drank. The chlorine dioxide is traditionally used for disinfection applications (e.g. in the hospitals, for the swimming pools, also added to the water supply), but in this case MMS is claimed to be used as a treatment for the diseases. Although the FDA [warned](http://www.fda.gov/Safety/MedWatch/SafetyInformation/SafetyAlertsforHumanMedicalProducts/ucm220756.htm) consumers to not to consume it, because it may cause harm to health.

However my question isn't about whether it cause any harm to health, but whether the claim in the video supported by evidence.

So my main question: Is that true that Red Cross cured malaria cases using activated [chlorine dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_dioxide)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Red Cross itself denies that the video is accurate. Their statement categorically denies that they were involved in any clinical trials for Malaria.

You can find the following statement on the website of the International Federation of Red Cross and Red Crescent Societies (IFRC):

> **IFRC strongly dissociates from the claim of a ‘miracle’ solution to
>   defeat malaria**
>
> The International Federation of Red Cross and
>   Red Crescent Societies (IFRC) dissociates itself in the strongest
>   terms from the content of the recent Master Mineral Solution
>   newsletter (May 2013) entitled “Malaria finally defeated” and
>   supporting YouTube video. IFRC does not support or endorse in any
>   manner the claims made in relation to this project, and has at no time
>   been involved in ‘clinical trials’ related to malaria treatment.
>
> Malaria affects 219 million people every year, killing a child
>   somewhere in the world every minute. As a matter of policy, IFRC
>   adheres to World Health Organization (WHO) guidelines which state the
>   only way to combat malaria is to scale up prevention, diagnosis and
>   treatment.
>
> The IFRC expresses its support to the Uganda Red Cross Society and
>   recognises that it has been spearheading prevention programmes across
>   the country over the last decade, as auxiliary to their public
>   authorities and in line with WHO guidelines.
>
> http://www.ifrc.org/en/news-and-media/opinions-and-positions/opinion-pieces/2013/ifrc-strongly-dissociates-from-the-claim-of-a-miracle-solution-to-defeat-malaria/